# MATLAB- Identifying additional peaks from given consecutive waveforms having a waveform as reference

Tags: matlab, plot, signals, waveform

I was doing this problem where I had to differentiate between given two waveforms. I have plotted the waveforms and identified the maximas/peaks. My goal is to identify a peak that was not there in the first waveform, but is present in the second waveform. To the naked eye, it is quite simple to identify this. But please you help me with this with atleast the logic/concept or if possible the code in MATLAB itself.

**Note:** I want to be able to detect the 8th peak as the different peak Plot of 2 waveforms where my intention is to detect the 8th peak that stands out much different that other peaks of the given 2 waveforms.

[image: 1]

**---EDIT---**

Spent time on filtering the signal to remove unnecessary peaks.

1. The below plot represents the reference frame:

[Reference/Calibration Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4ZHS.png)

From the plot it is evident that there exists 3 peaks, namely-1,2,3.
This plot is used as reference, and any other plot that is computed later, we should be able to ignore these peaks(that may not lie on the exact same coordinates but somewhere nearby).

2. The below plot is a measurement taken in real-time, after the above calibration reading:

[First Measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLr8X.png)

Here, in this plot my goal is to identify the peak labelled 3.

**Note:** Here the peak labelled-3 does not correspond to peak labelled-3 in the calibration plot

While using the calibration plot as reference, I have to ignore peak-1,2 in this plot and just identify the peak-3, since it is not present in the former (meanwhile ignoring the peak-3 in the calibration plot since it does not show up in this plot).

3. Similarly, consecutive reading plots are shown below:

Peak to be identified here is peak labelled 3.

[Second Measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK9tX.png)

Peak to be identified here is peak labelled-3.

[Third Measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29xf.png)

**Looking at the consecutive plots, its evident that the static peaks are to be ignored in all readings and only the new peaks that appear to be moving along consecutive readings are to be identified.**

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to settle on the criteria that will allow peaks to be considered as **comparable**.

Are you just going by the **order of appearance** (1, 2, 3, etc.) of the peaks? Or do you also need the peaks to be **close to each other** on the X-axis?*

For example, let's say that the peaks labelled "1" in your plot had very different Y-values but had the same X-values as in your plot (i.e., they were far apart on the X-axis). Would your answer include this peak? Or would you discard it because they were too far apart?

Depending on your requirements, I can think of two criteria to consider your peaks to be comparable:

- They are **close to each other** on the X-axis (say, within 1 unit of each other)
  **and / or**
- They have the **same order of appearance** in the curves, so you never compare peak i of one curve with peak j of the other when i ≠ j

Once you have identified all comparable peaks, then you just need to check if their Y-values exceed some threshold. This threshold could be either **relative** or **absolute** or **both**:

- **Absolute**: |Y2 - Y1| > T, where T is some threshold like, say, 10 units
- **Relative**: |Y2-Y1|/B > t, where B could be min(Y1, Y2) or Y1 or Y2 or some other baseline value and t is some relative threshold like 0.2
- **Both**: e.g., should be, say, at least 5 Y-units apart but also more than 20% apart on a relative scale -- this sort of criterion usually works the best in practice

Finally, note that while we *think* that we are good at catching differences in peaks with our eyes, this is not really the case. There will always be gray areas where even a human won't be sure about whether to consider the peaks to be far apart or not.
This is why you should probably go through the following exercise to develop some discipline:

- Randomly generate a lot (say, a couple of dozen pairs) curves like the ones in your plot
- Prepare *List A*: identify peaks you consider to be comparable and significantly different

  - For each such peak, record the difference in Y-values
- Prepare *List B*: identify peaks that you consider to be comparable but **not** significantly different

  - For each such peak, record the difference in Y-values
- Study the distribution of values (min, max, mean, etc.) in lists A and B

This exercise will help you stay consistent and guide your choice of thresholds. Without going through this exercise, you will likely use your intuition to guess poor initial values for thresholds. You may then update the thresholds to feel better about the results but you would then have run out of precious, real-world test data and the next, unseen pair of curves might again fail to meet your expectations.

Next, use the exercise above to pick some thresholds (such as t and T above) and test them on a few more randomly generated curves. Look at how many **false positives** (detected a significant difference when a human would have said the peaks are close) and **false negatives** (failed to detect a significant difference when a human would have said otherwise) emerge. These are unavoidable with real data but make sure you're okay with the number of hits and misses. If not, adjust the thresholds and redo these steps.

Once you're satisfied with performance of the thresholds on the mock data, you can run the program on your real data, with a better expectation and understanding of the performance of the code.

I haven't worked with Matlab in a while -- Python is more convenient these days. If you make your requirements a bit more clear, I'm sure someone will provide code.

--

*You might find the concept of **cross-correlation** to be useful in this regard but you need to be careful about the technicalities -- it might be too complex for your simple use case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Will try executing them all. My goal is to detect the peaks that are not present in the reference plot. Since the observations were made in real-time, the unwanted/noisy peaks do not necessarily overlap. Yes, the peaks should be close as well on x-axis but as you can see for example, Peak-1 in both graphs are unwanted but they do not overlap. They lie far apart so they are not comparable in x-axis. You can also observe that after the 7th peak none of the peaks overlap. My goal is to find out the extra peak that exists in second plot, keeping first plot as reference.

Comment: My goal is to identify the peak that stands out from the reference plot, which in this particular observation is the 8th peak. If you want some more samples for understanding, I'd be happy to post them with appropriate labelling.

Comment: When you say "the peak", is it guaranteed that there will be just one peak? Additional examples would definitely be useful if you can link them via imgur.com or such.

Comment: I've added an "EDIT" section to the Post with more sample readings and detailed explanation. Kindly request your suggestions.